# Boundary Value Problem has no solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Given the folllowing ODE, find its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions:

$$
x^2y''-xy'+\lambda y=0,y(1)=y(L)=0,L >1
$$

Doing the analysis for each condition of $\lambda, i.e.,\lambda=0, \lambda>1, \lambda<1, \lambda=1$ (the last three values came using a analysis of euler-cauchy equation).

But I didn't found any solution using this method, always I found only the trivial solution, $y=0$.

Can someone show me a better approach?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Hint: $x^{a+bi} = x^a(\cos(b\ln x) + i\sin(b\ln x))$

Comment: **Hint**

If you try $y=x^a$, you should arrive to something simple before using any condition.

Comment: But using this, I found that y=0 anyways

Comment: Oh, I solved! Thanks @whpowell96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Euler equation $x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+\lambda y(x)=0$ has a solution $x^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ satisfies the indicial equation
$$
                \alpha(\alpha-1)-\alpha+\lambda=0, \\
         \alpha^2-2\alpha+\lambda = 0.
$$
This equation has solutions
$$
             \alpha = 2\pm\frac{\sqrt{4-4\lambda}}{2}=2\pm\sqrt{1-\lambda}
$$
You can choose a specific solution $y(x)$ that satisfies $y(1)=0,y'(1)=1$. Such a solution may be written as
$$
         y(x,\lambda)=\frac{x^{2+\sqrt{1-\lambda}}-x^{2-\sqrt{1-\lambda}}}{2\sqrt{1-\lambda}}.
$$
Note that the added condition $y'(1,\lambda)=1$ forces the function $y(x,\lambda)$ to be an entire function of $\lambda$, which means that the eigenvalues are the zeroes of an entire function of $\lambda$. So the eigenvalues have no finite point of accumulation, which can be demonstrated directly by rewriting $y(x,\lambda)$ in the form
$$
    y(x,\lambda)=x^2\frac{e^{\sqrt{1-\lambda}\ln (x)}-e^{-\sqrt{1-\lambda}\ln(x)}}{2\sqrt{1-\lambda}}
   = x^2\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{1-\lambda}\ln(x))}{2\sqrt{1-\lambda}}
$$
Therefore, the eigenvalue equation $y(L,\lambda)=0$ has the form
$$
   \sinh(\sqrt{1-\lambda}\ln(L))=0,\;\; \lambda\ne 1,
$$
which can be explicitly solved:
$$
    \sqrt{1-\lambda}\ln(L)=\pm i\pi,\pm 2i\pi,\cdots \\
    (1-\lambda)\ln(L)^2=-\pi^2,-4\pi^2,-9\pi^2,\cdots \\
    1-\lambda=-\frac{\pi^2}{\ln(L)^2},-\frac{4\pi^2}{\ln(L)^2},-\frac{9\pi^2}{\ln(L)^2},\cdots \\
   \lambda=1+\frac{\pi^2}{\ln(L)^2},1+\frac{4\pi^2}{\ln(L)^2},1+\frac{9^2\pi^2}{\ln(L)^2},\cdots .
$$